# iOS: Can't restore consumable purchases in the sandbox environment

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I've created some consumable IAPs and test it in the sandbox environment.
However, restoring purchases doesn't return any transaction even i've purchased few items...

How do i test it?
Here is my code

button's trigger to activate restore purchases

```
if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
                print("restore payment")
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
            }
```

Restore purchases `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`

```
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print("\(queue.transactions.count)")
        for transaction:AnyObject in queue.transactions
        {
            let trans : SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            //var identifier : NSString = trans.payment.productIdentifier
            let identifier : NSString = trans.originalTransaction!.payment.productIdentifier

            print("pdi \(identifier)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Consumable products` can't be restored from apple server. For consumable products you will have to manage the purchase list manually at your own server.
If you want restorable products then you can simply do it with `Non-Consumable` products in iTunes.

Comment: So it means every times user make a purchase, i have to store the receipt base on their user ID? And i handle the restoring process by myself?

Comment: Yes. You can't restore it from apple server.

Comment: If it helped you then please don't mind to accept the answer.